# SSRS Background Color Expression Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I am trying to make an expression which will make the background color change based on FileType and the DriveLetter associated with the FileType. When I preview the report, this error appears:

> Warning   1   [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The BackgroundColor expression
>   for the text box ‘Physical_Name’ contains an error: Input string was
>   not in a correct format.

Does this mean there is a issue with the datatype for this column or does anyone see something wrong with the expression i used?

Here is the expression:

```
=Switch(((Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "F") OR (Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "T")) AND (Fields!FileType.Value = "MDF"), "Lime", 
        ((Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "F") OR (Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "T")) AND (Fields!FileType.Value = "LDF"), "Red")
```

Thanks.

Comment: save your report close Visual Studio and open it again, weird but works sometime..

Comment: Do you get the error for all conditions or just for a non-match (else) condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!FileType.Value = "MDF" AND (Fields!DriveLetter = "F" OR Fields!DriveLetter = "T"),"LIME",IIF(Fields!FileType.Value = "LDF" AND (Fields!DriveLetter = "F" OR Fields!DriveLetter = "T"),"RED",""))
```

Comment: All your "Fields!DriveLetter" need to end with ".Value"